# Using variables from a struct within an array of structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

So the primary objective here is to take input from the user and store it in an array where each element in the array is a struct srecord. I would like to be able to retrieve the strings fname and lname as well as the score. This is crucial because I am going to also design other methods that will calculate the average of all students in the array and tell which students have the highest or lowest score.

For example in fill_in_srecord_array, if I wanted to print out the information in a[i] after running fill_in_srecord, would this be the proper line?

```
 printf("%s %s: Score= %d\n", a[i].fname, a[i].lname, a[i].score);
```

But this does not compile, so what is wrong here?

Is my fill_in_srecord method working properly and actually filling in the array properly?

For future reference, what is the best way to access variables from a struct being stored in an array?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct srecord {
  char fname[20]; /* first name */
  char lname[20]; /*  last name */
  int score;
};

void fill_in_srecord(struct srecord *r){

  struct srecord new_student; //declare a new student record
  r = &new_student; //assign a value to the pointer

  printf("Enter student first name: "); //request input
  scanf("%s", r->fname);
  printf("First: %s",r->fname);

  printf("\nEnter student last name: ");
  scanf("%s", r->lname);
  printf("Last: %s",r->lname);

  printf("\nEnter student score: ");
  scanf("%d", &(r->score));
  printf("Score: %d\n", r->score);

}

void fill_in_srecord_array(struct srecord a[], int len){

  a[len];
  //struct srecord *p; //srecord pointer

  for(int i = 0; i<len; i++) {

    fill_in_srecord(&a[i]); 

  }
}

int main(){

  struct srecord students[2];

  fill_in_srecord_array(students, 2);

  exit (0);

}
```

Comment: `a[len];` is a mistake (take this line out)

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that in the `fill_in_srecord` function you do

```
struct srecord new_student;
r = &new_student;
```

This is problematic for *three* reasons:

1. First is that `new_student` is a *local* variable, and it will go out of scope and disappear once the function returns. Any pointers to it will be stray pointers and using them will lead to *undefined behavior*.
2. The second problem actually makes the first problem moot, because when you pass a value to a function in C the values are *copied* and the function only gets a copy. Modifying a copy (like e.g. `r = &new_student`) will of course not modify the original.
3. The third problem is that when the function is called, you pass a pointer to a valid and existing instance of the `srecord` structure. There's simply no need for the `new_student` variable or the reassignment of `r` inside the function. Modifying `r` directly will be enough.

So the solution is simply to not have the two problematic lines.

---

There's another thing as well, the statement `a[len];` that you have in the `fill_in_srecord_array` function it doesn't really do anything. But if it did anything it would lead to undefined behavior because you would index the array `a` out of bounds.

Comment: Thank you! Will fixing this also make the prints() statement above give proper output if I ran it in fill_in_srecord_array? @joachim

Comment: @Nasmarr Yes it should work, if you put the printout in the loop after the `fill_in_srecord` call.

Comment: I think `a[len];` is UB because of "if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undefined"

Answer (score 1):

Right now you were making changes to local variable , which is not accessible out of function block and changes made to it are not done on the variable in calling function itself .

When you pass address of `a[i]` to function ,and if you make changes to that in function ,`a[i]` will be modified in the calling function itself . Because the changes will be made directly to content at its address , that is to itself .

What you need to do is write your function like this -

```
void fill_in_srecord(struct srecord *r){

 /*  struct srecord new_student; //declare a new student record   */
 /*  r = &new_student; //assign a value to the pointer             */
   printf("Enter student first name: "); //request input 
   scanf("%s", r->fname);
   printf("First: %s",r->fname);
   printf("\nEnter student last name: ");
   scanf("%s", r->lname);
   printf("Last: %s",r->lname);
   printf("\nEnter student score: ");
   scanf("%d", &(r->score));
   printf("Score: %d\n", r->score);
 }
```